# How to get text from client side before saving the record using selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Need to get text from entered input field from client side before saving the record?

Comment: Did you considered reading the WedDriver docs? Just read it once through, to get idea what methods are available. Especially if you want to have "Guru" in your name :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getAttribute()` method of `WebElement`. You need `value` attribute. Like it is shown in my example:

```
driver.get("https://www.wikipedia.org/");
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='searchInput']"));
input.sendKeys("My Test");
System.out.println(input.getAttribute("value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant you do somthing like this.
Rather than getting a entered text why cant you enter a text that you already defined in your text.

```
 string EnteredTxt = "what ever the text";
 Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='searchInput']")).SendKeys(EnteredTxt);
```